# Parse issue using XML::XPath

Tags: xml, perl, xpath

I am trying to parse a xml file (serverslist2.xml) with contain a server list in the format:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<servers>
  <aplication name="App1">
    <env name="Test">
      <appliance alias="app1t1" conname="10.0.0.10:80" />
      <appliance alias="app1st1" conname="10.0.0.10:443" />
    </env>
    <env name="Prod">
      <appliance alias="app1p1" conname="10.0.1.10:80" />
      <appliance alias="app1sp1" conname="10.0.1.10:443" />
      <appliance alias="app1p2" conname="10.0.1.11:80" />
      <appliance alias="app1sp2" conname="10.0.1.11:443" />
    </env>
 </aplication>
  <aplication name="App2">
    <env name="Test">
      <appliance alias="app2t1" conname="10.0.0.20:80" />
      <appliance alias="app2st1" conname="10.0.0.20:443" />
    </env>
    <env name="Prod">
      <appliance alias="app2p1" conname="10.0.1.20:80" />
      <appliance alias="app2sp1" conname="10.0.1.20:443" />
      <appliance alias="app2p2" conname="10.0.1.21:80" />
      <appliance alias="app2sp2" conname="10.0.1.21:443" />
    </env>
 </aplication>
</servers>
```

I may receive an "alias" value (which I know it is unique) in a variable and need to retrieve the "conname" value.

So far, my code (testxpath.pl) looks like:

```
#!/usr/bin/perl 
use XML::XPath;

my $file = 'serverslist2.xml';
my $xp = XML::XPath->new(filename => $file);

my $server = app2st1;

print "Starting Test1:\n";
foreach my $test1 ($xp->find('//appliance[@alias="' . $server . '"]')->get_nodelist) {
    print "Test1 output: " , $test1->find('@conname') , "\n"; 
    } ;

print "Starting Test2:\n";
my $test2 = $xp->find('//appliance[@alias="' . $server . '"]')->get_nodelist ;
print "Test2 output: " , $test2->find('@conname') , "\n";
```

The curious thing is that Test1, using a foreach branch, works, but without it, it fails, even using basically the same commands.

The output is:

```
$ ./testxpath.pl
Starting Test1:
Test1 output: 10.0.0.20:443
Starting Test2:
Can't call method "find" without a package or object reference at ./testxpath.pl line 16.
```

Can someone clarify what is wrong and how to fix it? 
Also if there would be a better approach using this or some other perl XML handling lib, it would be appreciate.
(P.S.: I may not simply 'grep' using some regexp because the xml will always fit on this standard, but not necessarily will be "well printed")

Regards
Renato

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[`->get_nodelist`](https://metacpan.org/pod/XML::XPath::NodeSet#get_nodelist) returns a list.

You therefore must put your variable in parenthesis or it will just be assigned the list count instead of the first value:

```
my ($test2) = $xp->find(qq{//appliance[\@alias="$server"]})->get_nodelist;
```

Alternatively, since you're just looking for a single value, you can use the [`findvalue`](https://metacpan.org/pod/XML::XPath#findvalue-path-context) method:

```
print "Starting Test3:\n";
my $conname = $xp->findvalue(qq{//appliance[\@alias="$server"]/\@conname});
print "Test3 output: $conname\n";
```

Here is a full working working script:

```
#!/usr/bin/perl 
use strict;
use warnings;

use XML::XPath;

my $file = 'serverslist2.xml';
my $xp   = XML::XPath->new(xml => do { local $/; <DATA> });

my $server = 'app2st1';

print "Starting Test1:\n";
foreach my $test1 ( $xp->find(qq{//appliance[\@alias="$server"]} )->get_nodelist ) {
    print "Test1 output: ", $test1->find('@conname'), "\n";
}

print "Starting Test2:\n";
my ($test2) = $xp->find( qq{//appliance[\@alias="$server"]} )->get_nodelist;
print "Test2 output: ", $test2->find('@conname'), "\n";

print "Starting Test3:\n";
my $conname = $xp->findvalue(qq{//appliance[\@alias="$server"]/\@conname});
print "Test3 output: $conname\n"; 

__DATA__
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<servers>
  <aplication name="App1">
    <env name="Test">
      <appliance alias="app1t1" conname="10.0.0.10:80" />
      <appliance alias="app1st1" conname="10.0.0.10:443" />
    </env>
    <env name="Prod">
      <appliance alias="app1p1" conname="10.0.1.10:80" />
      <appliance alias="app1sp1" conname="10.0.1.10:443" />
      <appliance alias="app1p2" conname="10.0.1.11:80" />
      <appliance alias="app1sp2" conname="10.0.1.11:443" />
    </env>
 </aplication>
  <aplication name="App2">
    <env name="Test">
      <appliance alias="app2t1" conname="10.0.0.20:80" />
      <appliance alias="app2st1" conname="10.0.0.20:443" />
    </env>
    <env name="Prod">
      <appliance alias="app2p1" conname="10.0.1.20:80" />
      <appliance alias="app2sp1" conname="10.0.1.20:443" />
      <appliance alias="app2p2" conname="10.0.1.21:80" />
      <appliance alias="app2sp2" conname="10.0.1.21:443" />
    </env>
 </aplication>
</servers>
```

Outputs:

```
Starting Test1:
Test1 output: 10.0.0.20:443
Starting Test2:
Test2 output: 10.0.0.20:443
Starting Test3:
Test3 output: 10.0.0.20:443
```

Comment: findvalue() works exactly as what I was looking for. This is a much more elegant solution. Tkx Miller.

Comment: One additional finding regarding `findvalue` :
For printing, that worked pretty fine, but for assignment I found that this worked better:

`    my $conname = $xp->findvalue(qq{//appliance[\@alias="$server"]/\@conname})->value(); `

This is because `findvalue` returns an `XML::XPath::Literal` object instead of a string, as `value()` would do.

Comment: Yes, [`findvalue`](https://metacpan.org/pod/XML::XPath#findvalue-path-context) returns an [`XML::XPath::Literal`](https://metacpan.org/pod/XML::XPath::Literal).  You can use [`->value()`](https://metacpan.org/pod/XML::XPath::Literal#value) to access the string representation, but that is also overloaded via the quote operator.  `"$conname"`